# How to set routes for multiple subnets with two interfaces?

Tags: zabbix

I have Ubuntu Server with Zabbix. 2 interfaces:

```
eth0 (main network for apache, ssh etc)
adress: 10.0.10.11/24
gateway4: 10.0.10.254

eth1:
adress: 10.0.2.10/24
gateway: 10.0.2.1

network 10.0.2.0 got subnets:
10.0.0.0
192.168.7.0
192.168.15.0
192.168.0.0
192.168.30.0
192.168.40.0

network 10.0.10.0 got subnets:
192.168.7.0
192.168.20.0
192.168.25.0
192.168.50.0
192.168.60.0
192.168.70.0
```

How to make routes (or something else) to ping without selecting specific interface?

```
$ ip route
default via 10.0.10.254 dev eth0 proto static
default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1 proto static
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.254
10.0.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.11
```

Comment: Read `man ip ip,route`

Comment: I read about it but my knowledge in networks is poor, i'm not it technican so i'm asking here for help.